# Transactional error while commiting

Tags: java, ejb, jta, stateful

I am trying to solve this error in Payara41 server Java EE 7, this sample works on WildFly-9 Java 7 EE and on Glassfish-3.1 Java EE 6 (without `@Transactional` and `@TransactionalManagement`)

```
@Stateful
@Transactional  //default TxType.REQUIRED
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class ImprovementDaoImpl extends AbstractBaseDaoClass implements ImprovementDao {

    /*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction tx;
...
}
```

Here's some stacktrace, what apperas after executing `tx.flush();`:

`javax.transaction.TransactionalException: Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRED encountered exception during commit javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
(...)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.`

So far I've tried to use interceptor and `@TransactionAttribute`, but none helped...

Thanks for any advice/help! :)

Comment: Isn't `@Stateful`  and `@TransactionalManagement` enough? Why you need here `@Transactional`?

Comment: @slwk Error is same.. :|
In WildFly this was required, really don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but hopefully this helps someone out there...

Question 21363423: [Throwing an application exception causes TransactionalException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363423/throwing-an-application-exception-causes-transactionalexception) says

> You are throwing an exception from a method whose invocation will be
>   intercepted at runtime and additional logic wrapped around it:
>
> ```
> transaction management;
> exception handling.
> ```
>
> Your exception cannot transparently jump over that logic, and the
>   specification (probably) says a TransactionalException will be thrown,
>   wrapping your original exception...

Question 18888572: [How do you find out what Exception caused the CDI Transaction Rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888572/how-do-you-find-out-what-exception-caused-the-cdi-transaction-rollback/20140096)

Shows how to use a CDI Interceptor to catch the exceptions.  I can't tell from the limited info from the OP what his/her specific issue is, but when I received this exception I has to review the WebLogic server log and found the entry where it told me a unique contraint was violated..  Time to add some interceptors...